# TListBoxItem.ItemData.Details doesn't work

Tags: delphi, listbox, listboxitem

My situation is illustrated/explained with this screenshot :

http://www.evolutiongraph.fr/chevereto/images/2015/02/11/Capture.jpg

In my ListBox, I want to display a text (titles), and details (articles) ; but it doesn't work : titles work perfectly, but ItemData.Details is not displayed, I don't know why :/
The variable `desc` is not empty, I've tested it. ItemData.Details still not appear.

Help me please :)

Comment: [`Read this`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Using_ListBox_Components_to_Display_a_Table_View_(iOS_and_Android)#Add_Detail_Information_to_an_Item).

Comment: Whichever StyleLookup you have selected is not one which supports this detail.

Comment: Yes, I had already read; but I do not find any solution to my problem. StyleLookup property doesn't propose "listboxitembottomdetails" or anything else. Only "listboxstyle" or "transparentlisboxstyle"

Comment: It sounds like you're looking at the properties of the list control, rather than the items of the list. Styles can differ for each individual list item.

Comment: Ow, sorry ^^ I found these properties, but for this I have to add manually Items ?

Comment: Ok. My application is a RSS reeder so items are automatically added. So I have to change the default style. I have no idea where I can change this ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify the `TListBoxItem`'s `StyleLookup` to one which supports showing details. For example, `listboxitembottomdetail`. Keep in mind this property is changed on an item-by-item basis, not necessarily the entire list. You can specify this to be the default item style (for all new items) by modifying `TListBox.DefaultItemStyles.ItemStyle` rather than each individual item.

[image]

Comment: Okay, so I have to put somewhere in my code DefaultItemStyles.ItemStyle:=listboxitembottomdetail; ? Sorry, I'm beginner in Delphi :/

Comment: Better to set this permanently on the `TListBox` control in design, rather than in code (although via code shouldn't hurt).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. As my items are generated automatically, how can I set this in design ? I do not create any item by myself in the designer :O And if I put this in my code, there's an error

Comment: Set it on the list box control... Like I said, you can find it at `TListBox.DefaultItemStyles.ItemStyle` without having any items.

Comment: Oow, okay, I see. But even like this, it still doesn't work : http://www.evolutiongraph.fr/chevereto/images/2015/02/11/CaptureQdqz0.jpg

Comment: Do you use platform views in the IDE? If so, which one did you make this change on? How are you populating these items?

Comment: Euhm, sorry I don't understand. I'm not English native, and I'm just a beginner ^^ I do not know what is a platform layout ^^

Comment: Edited, I meant platform view. What version of Delphi are you using? That makes a huge difference.

Comment: My version is : Embarcadero® Delphi XE7 Version 21.0.17017.3725

Comment: Don't know what to say without seeing how you're actually populating the items in this list.

Comment: I put `TListItemBox.StyleLookup:='listboxitembottomdetail';` in the code and it works ! : http://www.evolutiongraph.fr/chevereto/images/2015/02/11/Capturerv5je.jpg  But apparently, there's restrictions on the number of characters possible. Is it possible to put as many characters as I want ?

Comment: There might be, but that would be another question.

Comment: Okay :) Thank you so much taking your time for me, I really appreciate it ! Thanks !